# Energy dependence of integrating dosimeters

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, applied-physics, experimental-technology, radiometry

[image]

The graph shows the relative response of a dosimeter at different energies, normalized to 1.25 MeV Co-60 gamma rays. Curve A is the graph of the equation

$$
\frac{\bigg(\frac{r}{X}\bigg)_\bar{E}}{\bigg(\frac{r}{X}\bigg)_{1.25}} = \frac{\bigg[\frac{(\mu_{en}/\rho)_g}{(\mu_{en}/\rho)_{air}}\bigg]_\bar{E}}{\bigg[\frac{(\mu_{en}/\rho)_g}{(\mu_{en}/\rho)_{air}}\bigg]_{1.25}}
$$

I understand that we see an over response at energies below 100 keV due to the onset of photoelectric effect. However, for a LiF thermoluminescent dosimeter(TLD) we see a sharp drop on the response at very low energies. This is shown by curve C in the graph wherein the relative response with respect to absorbed dose(rad) drops to 80%.

What could have caused such drop in the dosimeter response?

NOTES
rad represents the absorbed dose(equivalent to J/kg) and R the exposure(equivalent to C/kg)